# .htacces fails due to "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects ..."

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following .htacces:

```
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ uploads/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

It fails with:
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

I guess it is because `uploads/(.*)$` also matches `uploads/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1`, but I don't know how to fix that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/.*?/.*$
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ uploads/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Made some changes. Can you try please again?

Comment: Post whole .htaccess to question ?. Also enable rewrite logs to see whats happening. RewriteLog "/path/to/logs/dir/rewrite.log" RewriteLogLevel 9 .

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/%{HTTP_HOST}/.*
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ uploads/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]`

Comment: Don't know how to make newlines :(
The log indicates that it rewrites uploads/test.jpg to uploads/my-domain.com/test.jpg and then to uploads/my-domain.com/my-domain.com/jpg etc...

Comment: I made one more change. Looks like variables are not allowed in RHS of RewriteCond. Please try and lemme know.

Comment: great ... Looks like variables are not allowed in pattern.

Comment: Oh, there is one thing though. Sorry.
It doesn't seems as I can have subfolders, for example /uploads/folder1/test.jpg then it fails.

Comment: yeah ..as we are considering that you will have hostdomain.com as only folders.

Comment: I guess I'll make another question for this problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the request only if the substitution makes sense, i.e. the new URL refers to an existing file:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/uploads/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.+)$ uploads/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L]
```